# procedure using loop in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqldatatypes

I used oracle

I want to declare a procedure that allows me to make insertion in a table

I try with this code without success

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADDSTEP(nbrStep character varying)
is
i integer :=0;

BEGIN
      FOR i IN 0..nbrStep LOOP
       INSERT INTO mytabletest
       VALUES (i);
    END LOOP;
    END;
```

I have this error :

```
PROCEDURE ADDSTEP compiled
Errors: check compiler log
```

Comment: `nbrStep character varying` should be `nbrStep varchar2`.

Comment: check compiler log. show errors

Comment: @FlorinGhita Should be `NUMBER`, as it is used later in the loop iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code:

1. > nbrStep character varying

There is no such data type called "**character varying**" in Oracle. For string you would use **VARCHAR2**. However, since you want to use it later in the loop for iteration, you need it to be **NUMBER**.

2. > FOR i IN 0..nbrStep LOOP

You need to iterate from 1 till the boundary.

3. > i integer :=0;

Not needed.

Modify the procedure as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADDSTEP(nbrStep NUMBER)
is
i integer :=0;

BEGIN
      FOR i IN 0..nbrStep LOOP
       INSERT INTO mytabletest
       VALUES (i);
    END LOOP;
    END;
/
```

Anyway, you entire **procedure** could be done in a single **INSERT SQL**. It is called row generator method.

Try,

```
INSERT INTO mytabletest 
   SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100;
```

Above, in place of `100`, you could use the value of your choice which is the value you are passing as parameter **nbrStep ** in the above procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Strange syntax of input variables. Corrected for Oracle -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE addstep(nbrstep IN NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 0.. nbrstep
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO mytabletest
      VALUES (i);
   END LOOP;
END;
```